# How to get max salary and count from employee table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have task where I need to filter in such a way that need to print the `max(salary * months)` and number of times the `max(salary * months)` occurred.

My data:

```
employee_id , name , months , salary
12          , Ami  , 15     , 1230
14          , Bik  , 1      , 678
15          , Tom  , 10     , 500
16          , Bob  , 12     , 3456
17          , Wil  , 1      , 9000
18          , Tim  , 14     , 1239
22          , Jil  , 15     , 1230
```

**Note**: the table as only `4` columns -> `employee_id, name, months, salary`

I have written a query where I am able to get `max(salary * months)`

Query #1:

```
select 
    max(msal) 
from 
    (select 
         employee_id, 
         name, 
         salary, 
         months, 
         (salary * months) as msal 
     from 
         employee);
```

Query #2:

```
select 
    e1.employee_id, 
    e1.months, 
    e1.salary, 
    e2.employee_id, 
    (e2.salary * e2.months) as earnings 
from 
    employee e1 
join 
    employee e2 on e1.employee_id = e2.employee_id;
```

Query #3:

```
select 
  emp,earnings 
from 
  (
    select 
      e1.employee_id as emp, 
      e1.months, 
      e1.salary, 
      e2.employee_id, 
      (e2.salary * e2.months) as earnings 
    from 
      employee e1 
      join employee e2 on e1.employee_id = e2.employee_id
  ) 
order by 
  earnings desc;
```

I calculated on paper these details:

```
15  * 1230   ->  18450
1   * 678    ->  678
10  * 500    ->  5000
12  * 3456   ->  41472
1   * 9000   ->  9000
14  * 1239   ->  17346
15  * 1230   ->  18450
```

According my analysis my output should be: `41472 1`

```
41472-> max(salary * months)
1     -> occurred twice
```

Comment: Isn't 41472 much greater than 18450?

Comment: @mathguy : Typo error .. your right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with emp (employee_id, name, months, salary) as
  2    (select 12, 'ami', 15, 1230 from dual union all
  3     select 14, 'bik', 1 ,  678 from dual union all
  4     select 15, 'tom', 10,  500 from dual union all
  5     select 16, 'bob', 12, 3456 from dual union all
  6     select 17, 'wil', 1 , 9000 from dual union all
  7     select 18, 'tim', 14, 1239 from dual union all
  8     select 22, 'jil', 15, 1230 from dual
  9    ),
```

Query begins here: rank values in descending order ...

```
 10  temp as
 11    (select salary * months max_value,
 12            count(*) cnt,
 13            rank() over (order by salary * months desc) rnk
 14     from emp
 15     group by salary * months
 16    )
 17  select max_value, cnt
 18  from temp
 19  where rnk = 1;           --> ... and, finally, fetch row(s) that rank as the highest

 MAX_VALUE        CNT
---------- ----------
     41472          1

SQL>
```

---

Although you didn't ask for it, but - such an approach is good because you can easily get - for example:

- the second highest value simply by modifying the `where` clause to

  ```
  where rnk = 2
  ```
- top 3 values

  ```
  where rnk <= 3
  ```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

You want to look at salary * month results, count their occurence and only show the top figure. So, group by salary * month, count and take the top row:

```
select salary * month, count(*)
from employee
group by salary * month
order by salary * month desc
fetch first row only;
```

Comment: The Simplest one! Applauds Man

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to write a Query

Incase any efficient way of writing Query. Please provide your solution

**Query :**

```
SELECT
    msal,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            months * salary AS msal
        FROM
            employee_salary
        WHERE
            ( months * salary ) IN (
                SELECT
                    MAX(months * salary)
                FROM
                    employee_salary
            )
    )
GROUP BY
    msal;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
MAX(salary * months)
COUNT(salary * months)
FROM employee
WHERE
salary * months IN (SELECT MAX(salary * months) FROM employee)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).